# NodeMCU - create public webserver

Tags: microcontrollers, wifi, esp8266

How would I go about creating a public web server so that I can control my NodeMCU v3 from anywhere in the world? I was thinking about flashing espruino on my board since I have more experience with web development than microcontrollers, but I found that to be more work than I'm willing to put in.   I would use Blynk but I want to control my NodeMCU from the web, not an app and I would also like the experience creating an IoT device from scratch.  I have seen many tutorials but they just show how to create a local web server (connecting to an IP address).  Are there any good tutorials out there for what I am looking for?  If someone has already done this, can you explain how you did it, or the tutorial you used?

Comment: This is a bit broad.  Likely you shouldn't create a public webserver, but rather subscribe to messages from an armored cloud relay like an MQTT broker or one of the many IoT-targeted service offerings.  If you really want to create a webserver you'll need to read up on how to make a webserver, how to configure a dynamic DNS service, and how to open ports on your firewall, all questions better pursued in subject-specific context than on IoT Stack Exchange.

Comment: See https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/how-do-consumer-iot-devices-typically-enable-internet-connection and https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/contacting-arduino-through-internet-without-port-forward and similar