# In what form should I store data in the cloud for a single device?

Tags: raspberry-pi, cloud-computing

This question looks similar to [What IoT services are available for storing/sending/publishing generic data in the cloud?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/600/what-iot-services-are-available-for-storing-sending-publishing-generic-data-in-t) though I haven't found a suitable answer yet.

I'm building a light/temp/humidity sensor for my wine cellar.

- I'd like to save these data a couple times per hour.
- I'd also like to be able to store extra data, such as reboots or extra sensors that might come later.
- I want to keep full control of historical data (which makes https://io.adafruit.com/ for example irrelevant).

Out of this data I'd like to make :

- Real time graph on a website
- Historical graphs in the long run.
- Alerting in case of issues, ideally with some automation to restart the device in the long run.

The device is a Pi 2, connected to Ethernet and power all the time. My app is a Java/Kotlin app with a JNI bridge so I do have the means to do pretty much what I want on the hardware side.

Ideally, I'd like to run things on the always free quotas from the Amazon, Google or Azure products.

I've been looking at solutions but haven't found anything satisfying yet.

- Using Firebase / Firestore could be a solution but I wonder how my schema can be catered to time series data. I also am unsure about making it future proof if I introduce new events.
- IOT specific products are usually expensive (0.65E/h for google for example and meant more for flocks of devices)

So far I am considering:

- Getting a influxdb database somewhere on a small server, but that sounds like overkill for something like 50 points a day?
- Using something like stackdriver, writing basically a log file with eahc line being a new measurement / event and then having some kind of pub/sub mechanism to pick up new data. But we are back to square one. How do I generate graphs from that data?

Searching for directions / link / advice here. I'd like to know how others are doing.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought of ddns services? If its only one device, why not access it directly?

Comment: Hey there. I guess you mean that I can use ddns to reach the device and read data directly? Yes indeed, that is not an issue. But I'm mostly interested in long term stats about the device though, ideally safe in case a device crashes or has to be restarted. Are you implying that I should run the database directly on the device? :)